# how to storing route params in nested routes in angular 4?

Tags: angular, router, angular-router, angular4-router

reason of using nested route for me is handling dynamically icon and back button for every page.i have abstract route because when i click to back button route params disappear and i put an abstract path to keep id and questionnaire type parameter in url.my abstract path is Questionaire.

```
      const routes: Routes = [
          {
             path: '',
              component: LayoutComponent, 
            children:[
              { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent,data:{icon:'fa-home'} },
              { path: 'QuestionaireList', component: QuestionaireListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-list-ul',previousState:'/Home'} },
              { path: 'ModifyMetaContent/:metaContentId/:title', component: ModifyMetaContentComponent,data:{icon:'fa-database',previousState:'/MetaContentList'}}

              { 
                path: 'Questionaire/:id',
                children:[
                { path: 'MetaContentList', component: MetaContentListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-database',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'}}

      ]},




              { 
                path: 'Questionaire/:questionnaireType',
              children:
              [     
                 { path: 'AddQuestionnaire', component: CreateQuestionnaireComponent,data:{icon:'fa-plus',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'}},      
              ]},
              { 
              path: 'Questionaire/:questionnaireType/:id',
              children:[ 
              { path: 'UpdateQuestionnaire', component: EditComponent,data:{icon:'fa-pencil',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'}  },
              { path: 'QuestionList', component: QuestionListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-pencil',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'} },
              { path: 'ImportQuestion',    component: ImportQuestionComponent,data:{icon:'fa-plus',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'}   },

            ]} ,
            ]},
      ];
```

MetaContentList.Component.html

```
   <a class="ui labeled positive icon small button" [routerLink]="['/ModifyMetaContent','',questionnaireTitle]">
  <i class="plus icon"></i>
 new metaContent
</a>
```

i store previous url in `snapshot.data.previousState` but when i click to `ModifyMetaContent`  i go to

> localhost:4200/ModifyMetaContent/...

and when i click to back button , `id` and `questionnairetype` disappear from url.when i to click to  ModifyMetaContent i expected go to :

> localhost:4200/Questionaire/b8b55b42-f39f-4359-93d0-0260ddf3827f/MetaContentList/ModifyMetaContent/...

and when i click to back button i expected  go to

> .../Questionaire/b8b55b42-f39f-4359-93d0-0260ddf3827f/MetaContentList/
>   but url set to 
>   localhost:4200/MetaContentList

and this error occurred :

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'MetaContentList'

i handle this case by nested states of angularjs ui-router.is any solution to this issue in angular2+ router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve this issue by change route structure and add a function for previousstate link in appcomponent:

my router:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
         path: '',
          component: LayoutComponent, 
            children:[
          { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent,data:{icon:'fa-home',previousState:[]} },
          { path: 'QuestionaireList', component: QuestionaireListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-list-ul',previousState:['/Home']} },

          { path: 'Questionaire/:id',children:[
            { path: 'MetaContentList', component: MetaContentListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-database',previousState:['/QuestionaireList']}},
            { path: 'ModifyMetaContent/:metaContentId/:title', component: ModifyMetaContentComponent,data:{icon:'fa-database',previousState:['Questionaire','MetaContentList']}}
            ]},
          { path: 'Questionaire/:questionnaireType',
            children:[{ path: 'AddQuestionnaire', component: CreateQuestionnaireComponent,data:{icon:'fa-plus',previousState:['/QuestionaireList']}}]},
          {path: 'Questionaire/:questionnaireType/:id',
            children:[ 
          { path: 'UpdateQuestionnaire', component: EditComponent,data:{icon:'fa-pencil',previousState:['/QuestionaireList']}  },
          { path: 'QuestionList', component: QuestionListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-pencil',previousState:['/QuestionaireList']} },
          { path: 'ImportQuestion',    component: ImportQuestionComponent,data:{icon:'fa-upload',previousState:['/QuestionaireList']}   },
        ]} ,
        ]},      
  ];
```

in my router 2 state is possible :

1. previous url is normal
2. previous url is nested url
   for implementation above state i put previousstate in an array if we are at  state 2 `array.length` is bigger than 1 .for embedding route params i create a method in appcomponent:

method for get lastchild :

```
 getSnapshot(route: ActivatedRoute){
                let lastChild = route;
                while (lastChild.firstChild) {
                lastChild = lastChild.firstChild;
                }
                return lastChild;
                }
```

method for get previous state :

```
getPreviousUrl(a):string{
  let previousState:string;
  const previousStateLength=a.snapshot.data.previousState ? a.snapshot.data.previousState.length :null;
  if(previousStateLength!==null){
   if(previousStateLength<=1 )
   {previousState=a.snapshot.data.previousState[0];}
   else{
     previousState='/';
     let parentParams=[''];
     let j:number=0;
     let b=a;
     while(b.parent){
       b.parent.params.subscribe((params)=>{
         Object.keys(params).map(key=>parentParams[j]+=params[key]+'/');
         for(let i=0;i<previousStateLength-1;i++){
           if(parentParams[j]!==undefined)
           previousState+=a.snapshot.data.previousState[i]+'/'+parentParams[j];
         }
        })
       b=b.parent;
     j++;
     }
     previousState+=a.snapshot.data.previousState[previousStateLength-1];

   }
   return previousState;
  }

}
```

and get data :

```
constructor(router:Router,route:ActivatedRoute) {

     router.events
     .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)

     .subscribe(e => {

       const lastChild=this.getSnapshot(route);
       this.routerIcon = lastChild.snapshot.data.icon;
       this.previousState=this.getPreviousUrl(lastChild);

   });
```

its work for me bu i want to maximality improve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' 
},
{ path: 'header', component: HeaderComponent},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent},
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
 { path: 'profile', children: [

    { path: ':id', component: ProfileComponent,children: [
    { path: 'profileform/:id',  component: ProfileformComponent,outlet: 'formOutlet', pathMatch: 'full' }]}]},


 { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: 'stone/:id',  component: StoneComponent,outlet: 'aux', children: [
    { path: 'steemblog', component: BlogComponent,outlet: 'blogoutlet'},
    {path: 'extlogin', component: ExternalLoginComponent, outlet:'blogoutlet'
    }]}]},
```

{ path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent}

```
       this.router.navigate(['/main',{outlets: { 'aux' : ['stone',this.state, {outlets: { 'blogoutlet' : ['steemblog',
        { 'access_token': this.accessToken, 'expires_in': this.expiresIn, 
      'userName':this.userName }]}}]}}]);

      }
```

Hi I am using outlets as well, but if you think those away you might be able to get yours to work? Not sure if this is exactly what you want but perhaps it helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. but its not work for me. i solve it my issue but i want to improve it to best practice .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPKSpuso6K0  using depth in the app.routnig  allows you to move states and create hierarchy. Could this help you? Not sure though if that would also work with your specific param problem. I would love to har as I want to do somthing similar!